# Logistic regression in R

Tags: r, regression

I have two matrix one X with all the feature values with 300000 rows and 14 columns, where columns represent the feature ids. for each I have another variable which defines labels Y which is of dimension 300000 x 1 either 0 or 1.

How do I calculate logistic regression from this matrix ?

Comment: @Seth, your link is directed to your local host. Find one online and paste that.

Comment: Here is a link to a walkthrough http://nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/courses/ling289/logistic.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is surprisingly easy.

```
m <- glm(Y ~ X, family = 'binomial')
summary(m)
```

In the future just try typing what seems obvious first.  You'll learn much faster if you're not afraid of making mistakes.

Comment: @Brandon Bertelsen - How does your comment relate to this concise and helpful answer?

Comment: I think it was a protest to a prior wording Roland.  I had a question in that I think was taken as accusatorial when it was really just a question.

Answer (score 0):

glmnet will also be ok for your problem

```
glm1=cv.glmnet(x,y,family="binomial",alpha=0)

prglm=predict(glm1,newx,type="response")
```